# My custom made plugin has "a new version available" which links to unrelated plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

My custom made plugin has "a new version available", also the "view details" link links to a completely unrelated plugin.

The plugin files begins with:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simple Contact Form 
Plugin URI: http://www.wilcoverhoeven.com
Description: Simple contact form
Version: 1
Author: Wilco Verhoeven
Author URI: http://www.wilcoverhoeven.com
*/
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you've got a naming conflict there -- assuming that your plugin is linking to [this](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-contact-form/) Simple Contact Form -- try changing the name to something like "Wilco's Simple Contact Form".

You'll need to update the plugin folder name and the main plugin file name as well.

**Update**

As [Aniket](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/104130/aniket) points out, you might need to force an update check on your site to get rid of the notice. You can do this by going to `http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/update-core.php?force-c‌​heck=1`

Comment: Changing both the name of the folder and the php file worked.

Comment: Awesome; I'm updating my answer to reflect this :)

Comment: You don't need to update the folder name if you renamed your plugin followed by force check update.

Comment: @Aniket It's probably safer to rename your plugin folder name, or at least check that it doesn't conflict with the name of another plugin

Comment: @Aniket, how can I force an update check?

Comment: Type the url of the website in the browser and append 'wp-admin/update-core.php?force-check=1' to the url and press enter. You must have [manage_network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_network) role to check for update or upgrade. Your final website url must look like [https://www.mywordpress.com/wp-admin/update-core.php?force-check=1](https://www.mywordpress.com/wp-admin/update-core.php?force-check=1)

Answer (score 6):

As i can see you have named your custom form as 'Simple Contact Form' which conflicts with this plugin name [Simple Contact Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-contact-form/). Try changing the name.
**Edit1:** You can also change the version if you don't want to change the name of the plugin. For eg: if you are prompted something like

> There is a new version of Simple Contact Form. [View version 14.13 details](http://#) or [update now](http://#).

then just rename the version of your plugin to 14.13 or above